# Programatically override EFS Root Directory for ECS containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

I'm attempting to use AWS ECS to allow users to run safely their own code. I want to mount an EFS subdirectory (pertaining to that specific user) when they create a container, but I cannot see a way to override this option.

Is there a way to programatically assign which directory of the EFS file system will serve as the root directory for the mounted volume in the EFS container?

Thank you!